# How can I combine two-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php

I need to combine 2 arrays. for example:

```
$array1 = array(
   [0] = array([0]=>1, [1]=>12-19-2014, [3]=>1113, [4]=>credit, [5]=>50000)
);
```

and

```
$array2 = array([0]=>1, [1]=>12-19-2014, [3]=>1111, [4]=>debet, [5]=>50000);
```

and become

```
$array = array(
    [0]=>array([0]=>1, [1]=>12-19-2014, [3]=>1113, [4]=>credit, [5]=>50000)
    [1]=>array([0]=>1, [1]=>12-19-2014, [3]=>1111, [4]=>debet,  [5]=>50000)
);
```

How I code that? Thanks for all answer.... :)

Thank for all who give me answer or comment. This is just an example. Now, I try to implement it into my script but I don't know why it is not working.

here is my table called table1:

```
||id || Date || explanation || debit_account || credit_account || debit || credit ||
```

Then if I have data (1, '12-19-2014', "buying mineral water", 1113, 1112, 5000, 0),
Users (or accountant ) want to see it as journal accounting standard like below:

```
||   Date    ||    Explanation       || Account || Debit || Credit ||
||12-19-2014 || Buying mineral water ||  1113   ||  5000 ||        ||
||12-19-2014 || Buying mineral water ||  1112   ||       ||  5000  ||
```

So I code them using CodeIgniter and my code in Models as below:

```
function listRecord()
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array1 = array (
      "id"=>$row["id"],
      "Date"=>$row["Date"],
      "explanation"=>$row["explanation"],
      "account"=>$row["debit_account"],
      "debit" =>$row["debit"],
      "credit"=>""   // or null
    );

   $array2 = array (
      "id"=>$row["id"],
      "Date"=>$row["Date"],
      "explanation"=>$row["explanation"],
      "account"=>$row["debit_account"],
      "debit" =>"", // or null,
      "credit"=>$row["debit"] 
    );
array_push($array1, $array2);
}

return $array1;
}
```

Then in Views :

```
foreach ($listRecord as $row) {
echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['date'].'</td<td>'.$row['explanation'].'</td><td>'.$row['account'].'</td><td>'.$row['debit'].'</td><td>'.$row['credit'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the result as I expected. All answer will be thankful.

Comment: just create another array, and push `$array1` and `$array2` to him.

Comment: `$array1[] = $array2;`

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: @Amy I have tried array_push($array1, $array2) and array_merge($array1, $array2) but I didn't get the result as I expected......

Comment: Well, what *did* you get?

Comment: @Lashane. Thanks, I would try

Comment: @deceze, I have edited my question above. I explain what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = $array1;
$array[] = $array2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array(
       '0' => array('1', '12-19-2014', '1113', 'credit', '50000')
    );
    echo 'Array 1<pre>';
    print_r($array1);

    $array2 = array('1', '12-19-2014', '1111', 'debet', '50000');
    $array_push=array($array2);
    echo 'Array 2<pre>';
    print_r($array2);
    $array3=array_merge($array1,$array_push);
    echo 'Array 3<pre>';
    print_r($array3);
    ?>
```

[image: array output]

Comment: Wow, that's... complicated.

Comment: Too much going on. Read Karthi's answer below.

Comment: this is my thought if you have any problem share your code

Comment: @JoeKasavage, yes. I get many example by searching in google but I don't know how to implement it into my scripts so I was editing my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Use *array_push*:

```
$array1 = array(
   array(1, '12-19-2014', 1113, 'credit', 50000)
);

$array2 = array(1, '12-19-2014', 1111, 'debet', 50000);

array_push($array1, $array2);

print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Hi @Karthi, I was editing my question above. Do you have any suggestion to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    function listRecord(){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from table1");
$rows=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row["id"];
    $array[] = $row["Date"];
$array[] = $row["explanation"];
$array[] = $row["debit_account"];
$array[] = $row["credit"];
array_push($rows, $array);
} return json_encode($rows);
}
```